# Android: Publishing and Signing same application for many customers

Tags: android, google-play

I have ready one application in Android that I am planning to sell to different clients. Each client will send me their own information to customize the layout of the application and maybe some functionality. The clients can decide if they want to give the application for free in the market or if it will be paid.

I know that it is not possible to upload the two applications with the same package name, so I will refactor the package name for each client.

According the Android documentation:

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate
>   before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to
>   identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be
>   signed by a certificate authority. Android apps often use self-signed
>   certificates. The app developer holds the certificate's private key.

I would like to know what is the best way to handle the publishing and signing of my application:

- Should I publish the customized version of my application for each client using my own google account or I should request/create one google account for each client?
- Regarding the signing procedure, Should I use the same key for each customized version of my application or I should create multiple keys in one Keystore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create multiple release apk with same key in Keystore but with different package name

Comment: "Should I publish the customized version of my application for each client using my own google account or I should request/create one google account for each client?" -- IMHO, neither. Don't accept the legal exposure, and have the clients distribute the apps themselves. "Should I use the same key for each customized version of my application or I should create multiple keys in one Keystore?" -- IMHO, neither. Use a dedicated keystore for each customer, and give the keystore to the customer along with the app.

Answer (score 0):

1- It is best that the client create their own Google play console and send you an invitation as admin, so that you can manage it for them (create new app, listing, publishing etc).

2- Sure you can use same key for all of them (i will recommend you that) as long as it is still valid (should be valid for at least 25 years)